# Add HttpHandler from HttpModule for static file not present in project

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

How to set httphandler from httpmodule for static file that is not present in poject.

Eg: If client requests a file called abc.xml thats not in my project,I need to add handler from my httpmodule and send some response to client how do i do it. My handler does not get called after adding it from httpmodule.

---

My HttpModule Code is as given below:

```
Public Sub Context_BeginRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 Dim Application As HttpApplication = CType(sender, HttpApplication)
 Dim CustomHandler As StorageHandler = New StorageHandler()
 Application.Context.Handler = CustomHandler
End Sub
```

The processrequest in customHandler does not get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending good 5hr, Got it .

Need to use RemapHandler,

```
    Application.Context.RemapHandler(CustomHandler)
```

and not

```
    Application.Context.Handler = CustomHandler
```